# Lengths of radii of ellipsoid cap

Tags: geometry, ellipsoids

[image]
Given $a,b,c$ and $h$. What would be the calculations for $d$ and $e$?

Comment: So I guess the surface of the geometry has
$$
\frac{x^2}{a^2} + 
\frac{y^2}{b^2} + 
\frac{z^2}{c^2}  = 1 
$$
Now, you know that $z=h$. Then you have to rewrite the equation to the form
$$
\frac{x^2}{e^2} + 
\frac{y^2}{d^2} = 1 
$$
where $e, d$ are some expressions $e=e(h)$ and $d=d(h)$.

Comment: Please show you have worked on the question.

Comment: I can try to be more specific, given that a, b, c and h respectively are 20m, 10m, 1m and 0,7m. The volume of the ellipsoid is 418,67m3 and the volume of the cap is 50,87m3. What i then need to do is find the surface area of the ellipse for the head of the cap, aswell as the corresponding lengths of its radii. After doing that i need to create a general expression for the lengths of the radii, still given a, b and c, but where the h is the height from the center of the ellipse cap and not from the center of the ellipse (so basically the new h is c-original h).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}+\frac{z^2}{c^2}=1$$

$x=0\rightarrow \frac{y^2}{b^2}+\frac{z^2}{c^2}=1$

$z=h\rightarrow \frac{(y=d)^2}{b^2}=1-\frac{h^2}{c^2}$

Therefore :

$d=\pm\frac bc\sqrt{c^2-h^2}$

Similarly:

$y=0\rightarrow \frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{z^2}{c^2}=1$

$z=h\rightarrow \frac{(x=e)^2}{a^2}=1-\frac{h^2}{c^2}$

Therefore :

$e=\pm\frac ac\sqrt{c^2-h^2}$

Comment: Thank you this was exactly what i was wondering!

Comment: @AbedaRijasji, you are welcome. Thanks for accepting. I would also up vote both answers.

Comment: I agree thank you for pointing it out, i almost forgot. I am new to this site, and currently working on a short essay regarding different shapes and their volumes.

Answer (score 1):

From

$$\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}+\frac{z^2}{c^2}=1$$ and $z=h$, you draw the equation of the section,

$$\frac{x^2}{a^2\left(1-\dfrac{h^2}{c^2}\right)}+\frac{y^2}{b^2\left(1-\dfrac{h^2}{c^2}\right)}=1.$$

Comment: This is also very helpful, thank you so much for taking the time!